# MySQLdb - fetchone()'s value does not change

Tags: python, mysql-python

THis is what I do in Python:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> connect = MySQLdb.connect(...)
>>> cur = connect.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('select max(Logid) from Log;')
1L
>>> cur.fetchone()
(1044122L,)
>>> cur.execute('select max(Logid) from Log;')
1L
>>> cur.fetchone()
(1044122L,)
```

---

This is what I did in mysql:

```
mysql> select max(Logid) from Log;
+------------+
| max(Logid) |
+------------+
| 1044116 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select max(Logid) from Log;
+------------+
| max(Logid) |
+------------+
| 1044123 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

At first, I think that is just fetchone()'s value is different from mysql's.
Because I searched in the different time, the value have been changed.

But, finally, I found, fetchone()'s value does not change at all...
Except I exit python, and run python again,the value will be changed...

Why?
I do execute select in MySQLdb, but why the value keeps same??

THX！！

Comment: You make two `select` in a row, so the result is likely to be the same. Have you tried to insert a row between the two `selects` and watch what is going on?

Comment: See [Python's MySqlDB not getting updated row](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1617637/222914)

Answer (score 0):

Use `connect.autocommit(True)` to keep the connect up-to-date.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943418/chronic-stale-results-using-mysqldb-in-python) for more.