# Python MySQLdb loop

Tags: python, mysql

Here is the pseudo code I am trying to achieve;

```
connect to db

While True:
execute query (SELECT * FROM requests WHERE state = 'NOT_STARTED'
foreach row in rows
  #process each row
```

Here is the code I have;

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import time

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(user='XXXX',
                         passwd='',
                         db='XXX',
                         host='XXX')

except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    raise e

while True:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    #db.begin()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE state = 'NOT_STARTED'")
    res = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    #db.commit()
    #db.close()

    print "No records: %d" % res
    time.sleep(3)
```

However, when I update the database, the number of records still shows as 1.

Comment: You're selecting the first column of the first selected row.  What are you trying to select exactly?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Python - so excuse me if I'm rubbish :). Basically, every iteration of the indefinate loop, I need to check if any new 'requests' have come in with the state = NOT_STARTED. If there is, process them accordingly, otherwise, wait 3 secs and check again.

Comment: Why don't you use `SELECT COUNT(*)`?

Comment: Solved :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943418/chronic-stale-results-using-mysqldb-in-python

`db.autocommit(True)`

Comment: @TomSothcott Albeit autocommitting is an option, I personally advise against it. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @Hyperboreus - do you have an alternative solution? Thanks.