# Flask app needs to restart after db change?

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I have a library management app. I'm not using an ORM (this is for a database project, not allowed to use an ORM) To checkout a book I'm doing form validation. Like so:

```
class CheckoutForm(Form):
    book_id = TextField('book_id', validators = [Required()])
    branch_id = TextField('branch_id', validators = [Required()])
    card_no = TextField('card_no',validators = [Required()])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self):
        rv = Form.validate(self)
        if not rv:
            return False

       # Get total copies of the book check if not 0
       cur.execute("""select SUM(No_of_copies) from book b, book_copies c where     b.Book_id = c.Book_id and
       b.Book_id = %s and c.Branch_id = %s""",\
            (self.book_id.data.strip(), self.branch_id.data.strip()))
        copies = cur.fetchone()[0]
        if copies == 0:
            self.branch_id.errors.append("Book not at this Branch.")
            return False

        # Get total available copies of the book in given branch check if not 0
        cur.execute("""select count(*) from book_loans l, book b, book_copies c where    b.Book_id = l.Book_id  and b.Book_id = c.Book_id and Date_in is NULL and b.Book_id = %s and c.Branch_id = %s""",(self.book_id.data.strip(),self.branch_id.data.strip()) )
        checked_out = cur.fetchone()[0]
        print checked_out
        avail_copies = copies - checked_out
        print avail_copies
        if avail_copies <= 0:
            self.branch_id.errors.append("No copies available right now.")
            return False
```

Now if i manually delete rows from book_loans table and If i don't restart the app, I keep seeing the old values (before db change) for avail_copies and copies. Why does this happen?

Comment: So as I understand, you open your app in the cmdline or a gui (mysql workbench, etc.), delete some of the entries from the database, and then when the queries are run in the app you still get the same data as before you deleted the entries?

Comment: well I did it from the mysql console. but yes that's what's happening.

Comment: The most likely culprit is the query cache. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474609/explicit-disable-mysql-query-cache-in-some-parts-of-program